# Denary number to hexadecimal

Tags: java, eclipse

As a homework, I was asked to write a program which would convert a denary number to hexadecimal. What I've created kinda works but as the output it gives me reversed number and I have no idea how to solve it (it is my first program).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Give a denary number: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int dec1 = sc.nextInt();
    String dec = Integer.toString(dec1);
    int zmienna;
    for(int i = 0; i < dec.length(); i++) {
        zmienna = dec1 % 16;
        dec1 = dec1 / 16;
        if(zmienna == 10) {
            System.out.print("A");
        }
        else if (zmienna == 11) {
            System.out.print("B");
        }
        else if (zmienna == 12) {
            System.out.print("C");
        }
        else if (zmienna == 13) {
            System.out.print("D");
        }
        else if (zmienna == 14) {
            System.out.print("E");
        }
        else if (zmienna == 15) {
            System.out.print("F");

        }
        else if (zmienna == 0 & i == dec.length() - 1) {
            System.out.print("");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(zmienna);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Just reverse the number after getting the final value, because if you apply the double dabble kind of method, The numbers start from the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change a little in your program i just tried to solve your problem and it works. I just added a `StringBuilder` and append characters and at the last reverse it.
**code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Give a denary number: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int dec1 = sc.nextInt();
        StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
        String dec = Integer.toString(dec1);
        int zmienna;
        for(int i = 0; i < dec.length(); i++) {
            zmienna = dec1 % 16;
            dec1 = dec1 / 16;
            if(zmienna == 10) {
                //System.out.print("A");
                sb.append("A");
            }
            else if (zmienna == 11) {
                //System.out.print("B");
                sb.append("B");

            }
            else if (zmienna == 12) {
                //System.out.print("C");
                sb.append("C");

            }
            else if (zmienna == 13) {
                //System.out.print("D");
                sb.append("D");

            }
            else if (zmienna == 14) {
                //System.out.print("E");
                sb.append("E");

            }
            else if (zmienna == 15) {
               // System.out.print("F");
                sb.append("F");


            }
            else if (zmienna == 0 & i == dec.length() - 1) {
                System.out.print("");
            }
            else {
                //System.out.print(zmienna);
                sb.append(zmienna);

            }

        }
        System.out.println(sb.reverse());
    }
}
```